# alternating sum with Barnes G functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $G(n)=(n-2)!(n-3)!\cdots 1!$ denote [the Barnes G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html).
I am pretty sure that
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{k^2-1}
(-1)^m\binom{k^2-1}m
\frac{G(k+n-m+1)}{G(n-m+1)G(k+1)(k^2)!}
=  n-2k^2-2k
$$   when  $k$ is    odd
and is
$n-\frac 12(k^2-1)$ when $k$ is even,
but I lack a proof. I'd already be happy for some references for identities regarding the Barnes function,  as this is all new to me.

Comment: @JMLandsberg This seems to be wrong. Plug $k=1$.  The LHS is $n!$, while your identity predicts $n-4$. What is the context in which you have arrived at this?